# Minecraft 1.13.2 Advancement pack not loading

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make an advancement system for a fnaf map I'm working on (don't judge). I've never had problems getting custom advancements in the game before, but for some reason, It's only loading in the root advancement. I'm using https://advancements.thedestruc7i0n.ca/ to generate the pack. I have included a critera for every advancement. Every advancement file looks like this:

```
{
    "__comment": "Made with TheDestruc7i0n's advancements generator: https://advancements.thedestruc7i0n.ca",
    "criteria": {
        "one": {
            "trigger": "minecraft:impossible"
        }
    },
    "display": {
        "title": {
            "color": "white",
            "text": "Survived Night One!"
        },
        "description": {
            "text": "That wasn't so bad, now was it?"
        },
        "icon": {
            "item": "minecraft:charcoal"
        },
        "frame": "task",
        "show_toast": true,
        "announce_to_chat": true,
        "hidden": false
    },
    "parent": "fnaf:progress"
}
```

When I run the command to get all advancements, only the root command gets obtained. If someone knows what's going on here, I'd like to know.

Edit: I've also tried to re-write the files by hand, like this, but even that had the same results.

```
{
"display": {
    "icon": {
        "item": "minecraft:black_stained_glass"
    },
    "title": {"Night Progress"},
    "description": {"Track your progress"}
},
"parent": "fnaf:root"
},  
"criteria": {
    "progress": {
        "trigger": "minecraft:impossible",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Every advancement file looks like this

not sure if you've tried this and failed or not, but see if you can edit the advancement files to what you need them to be.

if that fails, try to completely remove and readd the advancement pack and start over- there's a possibility it could've snagged.

Comment: I've tried making it again twice, once by hand and again using the generator. I've also tried changing the file structures around. There are many conflicting ways to organize the file structures, so I tried them all. Nothing has worked yet. The last thing I'm going to try is to edit someone else's pack if I can get that to work...

Comment: and that didn't work either... I feel like minecraft hates me. The pack that I used (blazeandcave's) loaded in game fine, but when I moved some files over to a new directory and edited it all properly to work with the new filenames and whatnot, it didn't work.

Comment: for clarification, the issue you're having is that your advancement packs aren't loading properly when placed in a separate directory. is that correct?

Comment: It's more just like they aren't working at all when I try to load them into minecraft. I've even tried re-writing them by hand and it still doesn't work. I've edited the main post to include the hand-written version.

Comment: okay. according to a [Minecraft 1.13-pre10 bug report](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-133861] answer, "the ``root`` advancement is not loading because ``criteria`` is not allowed to be empty. As consequence, its children are also not able to load." now, you said only the ``root`` gets obtained, and its children don't; **however, i should point out that the bug report also used the same generator you are.**

Comment: That was a good idea, however all my files have the criteria section properly filled out as shown on the minecraft wiki's page. I think I might have to just come up with my own in-game achievement tracking system instead. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: no problem! just comment here again if there's any breakthroughs made :D